# mod_rewrite for PHP's "lang?=" for more than one page?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I currently use the follwoing code in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect languages
RewriteRule ^(en|es|zh\-tw|zh\-cn)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

With that code, every time I type for instance, `/en` at the end of the URL, it redirects me to `/?lang=en` (loads the the English content from a PHP array):

For instance:

`example/en` redirects me to `example/?lang=en` while keeping example/en in the URL.

But I also have a **thanks.php** page and the code above clearly just work for the **index.php** page.

How can I make the rewrite rule to work for both `index.php` and `thanks.php` page?

Comment: What would you want the URL to look like for the `thanks.php` page?

Comment: @Tim Something like: www.example.com/thanks/en (for the English version) and www.example.com/thanks/es for the Spanish version).

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward way is just to do this:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|es|zh\-tw|zh\-cn)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^thanks/(en|es|zh\-tw|zh\-cn)/?$ thanks.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

If you want to make it more general, you have the option of white-listing files, like this:

```
RewriteCond $1    ^(thanks)/$ [OR]
RewriteCond index ^(index)$
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?(en|es|zh\-tw|zh\-cn)/?$ %1.php?lang=$2 [L]
```

...where `(thanks)` would be a pipe-delimited list of the files you wanted to have this functionality, or you can just accept every request as a pass-through to an existing PHP page:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|es|zh\-tw|zh\-cn)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/]?)/(en|es|zh\-tw|zh\-cn)/?$ $1.php?lang=$2 [L]
```